# Displaying raster images that are already georeferenced in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I have a number of historical surveys that I have already digitized, georeferenced, and clipped using ArcMap 10.6.1. My office wants to try using QGIS but I am completely new to the software.

Both the georeferenced images and the clipped raster files load into ArcMap without any issues. But when I add one of the georeferenced surveys (both .tif and .jpg) as a raster layer into QGIS, it does not display correctly. The CRS for the layer is the same as the other layers in the project but it appears in a completely different area of the project.

Further, when I import the raster clips of the same georeferenced survey, they appear in the correct location. But I am only able to import the grey-scale version, not the multiband colour (and we need them to be in full colour).

Is there a way to import these georeferenced images and raster clips into QGIS without having to redo all the georeferencing work I have already done?

Comment: The georeference should be right, I think what is happening is that the version of proj.4 the most recent versions of QGIS are built on goes a little silly and assigns the wrong projection to the layer (I get New Guinea projection when I load MGA55 rasters), which you can fix through the layer properties but that would be tedious if you've got a lot of them. Is your canvas CRS in a projection that uses the unit 'feet'? If this is the case then perhaps install an older version of QGIS before the silly CRS bug.

Comment: The issue of grayscale vs color can probably be fixed through the Layer Styling panel. Have a look at the options for multiband color and singleband pseudocolor. Layer style settings are not compatible between QGIS and ArcGIS, you will have to set them up separately in each program.

Comment: You can set the CRS of multiple layers at once. Select the layers in the layer panel, right click, set layer CRS. So if the problem is as @MichaelStimson describes, AND all your layers should have the same CRS, it will be a quick fix.